# Highlight and un-highlight div on onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have divs that I want to highlight with CSS with an `onClick`.

```
<div
  className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.activeCircle ? ' active' : '')}
  onClick={() => this.amountChanged(2)}>
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div
  className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.activeCircle ? ' active' : '')}
  onClick={() => this.amountChanged(5)}>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
<div
  className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.activeCircle ? ' active' : '')}
  onClick={() => this.amountChanged(10)}>
    <p>10</p>
</div>
```

My state `activeCircle` is a boolean which is set to `false` at the beginning.

In `this.amountChanged()` I set `activeCircle` to true.

But the problem is, that every div is highlighted `onClick` and I did not figure out how to do it without a `key`.

Comment: You need to check `this.state.amount === 2` or `5` or `10` based on the value that you are applying.

Comment: like this`className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.amount === 2 ? ' active' : '')}`

Comment: I just answered similar question :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61663988/8130690

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason all divs become active is because they depend on the same flag.

The most correct solution here would be to rely on the `set amount`

Assuming you set the selected amount in the state amount, you would implement the active logic like below

```
<div
  className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.amount == 2 ? ' active' : '')}
  onClick={() => this.amountChanged(2)}>
    <p>2</p>
</div>
<div
  className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.amount == 5 ? ' active' : '')}
  onClick={() => this.amountChanged(5)}>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
<div
  className={"amount-circle" + (this.state.amount == 10 ? ' active' : '')}
  onClick={() => this.amountChanged(10)}>
    <p>10</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just do something like that ?

```
<div onClick={(e) => e.target.classList.toggle('active')}>
  coucou
</div>
```

You won't depend on any flag, just the click target. Here is [a repro on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-91xc2i?file=index.js)